# odoo TypeError: search() takes at least 4 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I got error: TypeError: search() takes at least 4 arguments (2 given)

with this function:

```
def search(self, cr, uid, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, context=None, count=False):
    order='complete_name'
    for index, expr in enumerate(args):
        if expr[1] in ['like', 'ilike', 'not ilike', 'not like', '=like']:
            args[index][2] = re.sub(r"\s+", '%', expr[2])
    return super(stock_location, self).search(cr, uid, args, offset, limit, order, context, count)
```

on:

```
pickings = self.env['stock.picking'].search([('picking_type_id.id','=',picking_type_id),('state','=','assigned')])
```

I tried to change this function to new api with self.env but something wrong.

```
    def search(self, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, context=None, count=False):
        order='complete_name'
        for index, expr in enumerate(args):
            if expr[1] in ['like', 'ilike', 'not ilike', 'not like', '=like']:
                args[index][2] = re.sub(r"\s+", '%', expr[2])
        return super(stock_location, self).search(self.env, args, offset, limit, order, context, count

)
```

The function 'def search' is used in class stock_location(models.Model). So I tried to change this function from old api to new api. For searching the pickings I am using this function:

```
def _compute_can_validate(self):
        user_is_admin = self.env.user._is_admin()
        user_is_network_manager = self.user_has_groups('stock.group_stock_network_manager')
        owned_locations = []
        if user_is_network_manager:
        owned_locations = self.env['stock.location'].search([('user_ids','in',self.env.user.id),
                                                             ('type_id.code','=','network')])
```

Comment: But you realise the `list` you're passing and the instance of the class means you're only passing two arguments. What are you trying to do?

Comment: So you want to say that I don't need to change function def search to new api with self.env? The problem is not because of this?

Comment: check my answer, you have the parameters cr and uid that are not even being used... remove them and it should be fine

Comment: can you provide the method/function where you try to search for the pickings? i need the function/method definition to answer your question

Comment: I edited my question with function I am using to search for the pickings.

Answer (score -1):

```
def search(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # -> cr, uid??? what are these parameters for? You are not using them at all... 
    offset = kwargs.get("offset", 0)
    limit = kwargs.get("limit", None)
    order = kwargs.get("order", 'complete_name')
    context = kwargs.get("context", None)
    count = kwargs.get("count", False)
    for index, expr in enumerate(args):
        if expr[1] in ['like', 'ilike', 'not ilike', 'not like', '=like']:
            args[index][2] = re.sub(r"\s+", '%', expr[2])
    return super(stock_location, self).search(*args, **kwargs)
```

And for calling:

```
pickings = self.env['stock.picking'].search(('picking_type_id.id','=',picking_type_id),('state','=','assigned'))
```

See if it works now. You are creating a real mess with the way you are passing the parameters...

You are only passing two parameters and the method expects at least 4. One parameter is related to the 'self', which is related to the class object instance. Then you had three other parameters, which seems you are not even using, and then you have the list of arguments which is the only thing you are actually passing when you call the method.... using kwargs can provide you more flexibility and allow you to better implement the idea, including the super(stock_location, self).search part...

Comment: Thank you! I understand now. It works. Now I have another error:  if expr[1] in ['like', 'ilike', 'not ilike', 'not like', '=like']. TypeError: 'Cursor' object does not support indexing. I'll try  go further and search the problem that causes this.

Comment: sorry but no, that's not the right answer. He is facing an old API - new API problem here. Odoo switched his ORM method calls to a clearer way of using parameters. So they encapsulated some default parameters like cr, uid and context to `self.env`. Ofcourse this has to be done by a wrapper, because Odoo uses both ways parallel to be compatible to old code. I will try to give an answer later.

Comment: @CZoellner, for the question this is the right answer, which is solving the problem related to TypeError. If the API has other issues, then it is another topic. But feel free to provide a more complete answer that solves his problems entirely.

Comment: @RicardoSilveira i really would like, but i need to know, where his search call is done. I bet the wrapper is wrapping that call old api like, so he just needs to add cr, uid and context to his call.

Comment: but if he unzips the kwargs with **kwargs, he doesn't need to worry about it.